# Android: Calculator on showing 0 immediately after the dot

Tags: android, decimal, calculator

I am now working on a calculator, and everything works fine except for decimal places.

The calculator contains 2 displays actually, one is called fakedisplay for actual operations, and one is called Display, for presenting the desired format, ie adding commas.

When pressing 12345.678, Display will follow fakedisplay and present as 12,345.678, but if i press 12345.009, the fakedisplay will work normally as 12345.009, but the Display stuck as 12,345 until 9 is pressed, and at that time it will show 12,345.009 normally.

However, it is strange that when the user presses 0, there is no response, and until pressing 9, 009 will then immediately append.

I know this arise from the parsing code, but based on this, how could I amend the following code? I really cannot think of any solution... Many thanks for all your advice!

```
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    if (str.length()<15) {
        Fakedisplay.append("1");
    }

    DecimalFormat myFormatter1 = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###.#################"); 
    String str1=Fakedisplay.getText().toString(); 
    String stripped1 = Double.valueOf(str1).toString(); 
    stripped1 = myFormatter1.format(Double.valueOf(stripped1)); 

    if (stripped1.endsWith(".0")) 
        stripped1 = stripped1.substring(0, stripped1.length() - 2); 

    Display.setText(stripped1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to *not* strip off the `.0` in the code for every keystroke..

Instead, only strip off trailing zeros (assuming there's a decimal point in there of course) when the user calls for a *result.* Entering keys such as the digit keys `0` through `9`, the decimal point `.`, or the sign-change key `+/-` (what I'll call the entry keys) are not generating a result so should not strip trailing zeros.

However, non-entry keys, such as when you press `+` or `-` or `=` on your calculator can freely modify the number.

That will give you a display of the digits being entered as the user enters them but will still strip off trailing zeros when necessary.

You can do that with a modification to your statement (and, as mentioned, only doing this when the user presses a non-entry key):

```
stripped1 = stripped1.replaceAll("(\\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$","$1");
stripped1 = stripped1.replaceAll("\\.0$","");
```

The first statement removes all trailing zeros at the end of a decimal number (other than on if it's really an integer). The second takes care of that case.

No doubt I could make a single substitution if I gave it some more thought but that should be enough to get it functional.